# "How to fix 'class, interface, or enum expected' for my code

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am unable to find the solution for my code, I receive a 'class, interface, or enum expected' when trying to compile my code.

I have tried to research on how to fox the problem but I was unfortunately unable to do so as it seems like nothing is working for me...also if there are any errors that would lead up to it not working once this part is fixed, please let me know as to what I can change!

The code:

```
class MyDate {

//properties of date object
private int day, month, year;

//Constructor with arguments
public MyDate(int day, int month, int year) {
   this.day = day;
   this.month = month;
   this.year = year;
}

public boolean isValidDate() {
   if (month > 12 || month < 1 || day < 1) { // if negative values found
       return false;
   } else if (year <= 1582 && month <= 10 && day <= 15) { // starting date
                                                           // checking
       return false;
   } // for 31 day months
   else if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) {

       if (day > 31) {
           return false;
       }
   } // for 30 day months
   else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {

       if (day > 30) {
           return false;
       }

   } else if (month == 2) // February check
   {
       if (isLeapYear()) // Leap year check for February
       {
           if (day > 29) {
               return false;
           }
       } else {
           if (day > 28) {
               return false;
           }
       }
   }

   return true;
   }

   // checks if this year is leap year
   private boolean isLeapYear() {
   if (year % 4 != 0) {
       return false;
   } else if (year % 400 == 0) {
       return true;
   } else if (year % 100 == 0) {
       return false;
   } else {
       return true;
   }
 }

 /**
 * @return the day
 */
 public int getDay() {
   return day;
 }

 /**
 * @param day
 *            the day to set
 */
 public void setDay(int day) {
   this.day = day;
}

/**
* @return the month
*/
public int getMonth() {
   return month;
}

/**
* @param month
*            the month to set
*/
public void setMonth(int month) {
   this.month = month;
}

/**
* @return the year
*/
public int getYear() {
   return year;
}

/**
* @param year
*            the year to set
*/
public void setYear(int year) {
   this.year = year;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
   return day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
  }
} 

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyCalendar {

//enums for days of week
public static enum Day {
   SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY;
};

//enum for month of year
public static enum Month {
   JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST, SEPTEMBER, 
 OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER;
};

//enums for week numbers
public static enum Week { FIRST, SECOND, THIRD, FOURTH;
};

//to store Date object
private MyDate date;

//constructor taking mydate object
public MyCalendar(MyDate enteredDate) {
   this.date = enteredDate;
}

 //main method
public static void main(String[] args) {

   boolean validDate = false; //valid date false
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner for input
   MyDate enteredDate = null;

   //till valid date found
   while (!validDate) {
       System.out.print("Enter the date as day month year : ");
       //taking input and creating date object
       enteredDate = new MyDate(input.nextInt(), input.nextInt(), 
 input.nextInt());
       //validdating date object
       if (enteredDate.isValidDate()) { //if valid
           MyCalendar myCalendar = new MyCalendar(enteredDate); //creating 
calendar object
           myCalendar.printDateInfo(); //printing date info
           myCalendar.printCalendar(); //printing calendar
           validDate = true; //setting validate to true 
       } else {
           System.out.println("Please enter a Valid Date...");
       }
   }

   input.close();
 }

// returns number of days in current month
private int getNumberOfDays() {
   int days = 31;
   int month = date.getMonth();
   if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
       days = 30;
    return days;
}

//print calendar of this month
public void printCalender() {
   System.out.println("\n\nThe Calendar of "+Month.values() 
 [date.getMonth()-1]+" "+date.getYear()+" is :");
   int numberOfMonthDays = getNumberOfDays();
   Day firstWeekdayOfMonth = getDayOfWeek(1, date.getMonth(), 
 date.getYear());
   int weekdayIndex = 0;
   System.out.println("SUN MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT"); // The order of days
                                                       // depends on your
                                                       // calendar

   for (int day = 0; Day.values()[day] != firstWeekdayOfMonth; day++) {
       System.out.print("    "); // this loop to print the first day in 
his
                                   // correct place
       weekdayIndex++;
   }
   for (int day = 1; day <= numberOfMonthDays; day++) {

       if (day < 10) 

           System.out.print(day + " ");
       else
           System.out.print(day);
       weekdayIndex++;
       if (weekdayIndex == 7) {
           weekdayIndex = 0;
           System.out.println();
       } else {
           System.out.print(" ");
       }
   }
   System.out.println();
 }

//method to print about date information in literal form
public void printDateInfo() {
   System.out.println(date + " is a " + getDayOfWeek(date.getDay(), 
date.getMonth(), date.getYear())
           + " located in the " + Week.values()[getWeekOfMonth() - 1] + " 
week of "
           + Month.values()[date.getMonth() - 1] + " " + date.getYear());
}

/*
* gets day of the week, returns enum type Day
*
* day of week (h) = (q+(13*(m+1)/5)+K+(K/4)+(J/4)+5J)%7 ,q- day of month,
* m- month, k = year of century (year%100), J = (year/100)
*/
public Day getDayOfWeek(int day, int month, int year) {
   int q = day;
   int m = month;

   if (m < 3) {
       m = 12 + date.getMonth();
       year = year - 1;
   }
   int K = year % 100;
   int J = year / 100;
   //calculating h value
   int h = (q + (13 * (m + 1) / 5) + K + (K / 4) + (J / 4) + 5 * J) % 7;
   Day output = null;
   if (h < Day.values().length && h >= 0) {
       output = Day.values()[h - 1]; //getting respective enum value
   }
   return output; //returning enum value
 }

// get week number of current date
public int getWeekOfMonth() {
   int days = date.getDay();
   int weeks = days / 7;
   days = days % 7;
   if (days > 0)
       weeks++;
   return weeks;
  }

}
```

The error:

```
    MyCalendar.java:120: class, interface, or enum expected
    import java.util.Scanner;
    ^
```

Error given when I move the import to the top (UPDATED):

```
MyCalendar.java:164: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method printCalendar()
location: class MyCalendar
               myCalendar.printCalendar(); //printing calendar
```

Expected code:

```
java MyCalendar 29/02/2019
29/02/2019 in not a valid date, please re-input a valid date: 25/05/2019
25/05/2019 is a Saturday and located in the fourth week of May 2019
The calendar of May 2019 is:
SUN MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT
            1   2   3   4  
5   6   7   8   9   10  11
12  13  14  15  16  17  18
19  20  21  22  23  24  25
26  27  28  29  30  31
```

Comment: Did you try moving the import to the top of the file?

Comment: what is the file name of your code?

Comment: My file name is called MyCalendar.java

Comment: I have tried moving the import to the top of the file, I will update the post to show what error it gives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method `public void printCalender()` should be called or invoked as `printCalender()` not as `printCalendar()`

your method is `printCalender()` whereas you are calling `printCalendar()` which does not exist.

Comment: Correct answer. Since the English word is *calendar* with an *a* in the last syllable, I suggest changing the method name in the declaration to `printCalendar` instead of introducing the wrong spelling in the call.